# Multidimensionals Arrays indirect interaction

Tags: arrays

I've extracted the problem, I don't understand why cout << Array[0][8] writes 2 instead of 1.

http://gyazo.com/d159d3ea97b07f1551605daacd631703

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Array[8][8];

    Array[0][8] = 1;
    Array[1][0] = 2;

    cout << Array[0][8] << endl;
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It's because the range of each array if `0 - 7` not `8`. 8 just places it in the next dimension. `[0][8]` is the same as `[1][0]`

Answer (score 1):

i think array assigned this type:

An element in 2-dimensional array is accessed by using the subscripts, i.e., row index and column index of the array. For example:

```
type arrayName [ x ][ y ];
```

Where type can be any valid C++ data type and arrayName will be a valid C++ identifier.

A two-dimensional array can be think as a table, which will have x number of rows and y number of columns. A 2-dimensional array a, which contains three rows and four columns can be shown as below:

[image]

Thus, every element in array a is identified by an element name of the form a[ i ][ j ], where a is the name of the array, and i and j are the subscripts that uniquely identify each element in a.

```
 int val = a[2][3];
```

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question. It seems the asker grasps how an array works, just made a common mistake of trying to access the `n+1` slots of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Array index  Array[0][8] is not within the bounds of int Array[8][8]

If you leave this line commented as below it will still print 2. Perhaps it is getting some garbage value.

```
//Array[0][8] = 1;
```

Comment: Actually it's because the first line should read `Array[0][7]`

Comment: No its because both first line and the cout line should read Array[0][7]

Comment: I think you may be missing the point, they are looking for a 8 x 8 matrix, that would be defined as `Array [8][8]` and from the looks of it they want to place a 1 in the last slot of the first dimension, that should be `[0][7]` NOT `[0][8]` changing the definition in that way would not only cause an error but would just make it a 7 slot array.

Comment: I know that man! They need to remove it from the "cout<< " line too. That's what I'm trying to say @hoss

Comment: @hoss You know what out of bounds mean?

Comment: I honestly don't want to have an argument, but I think you should read the question again. Obviously I if you comment out the offending line it will 'fix' the issue, and changing the definition was not the question. If you just said line 5 should read `Array[0][7] = 1;` then that probably would have soled the issue. It's a common mistake.